# Handling CultureInfo in String.Format()

Tags: .net, globalization

I'm trying to satisfy all FxCop rules in a new library.  As such, I need to specify an IFormatProvider for all my String.Format() calls.  Example:

```
public string Example(string value) {
    return string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, 
                         "You entered: {0}", value);
}
```

It gets very tedious specifying CultureInfo hundreds of times, so I made a helper:

```
public string Example2(string value) {
    return CurrentCulture("You entered: {0}", { value });
}

private string CurrentCulture(string value, object[] objects) {
    return string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, value, objects);
}
```

This works, but I lose all my Resharper warnings if I malform the `"You entered: {0}", { value }` part.

Perhaps it's best to just use a short alias:

```
public string Example3(string value) {
    return string.Format(Current(), "You entered: {0}", value);
}

private CultureInfo Current() {
    return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
}
```

Any other ideas?

Comment: string.Format(String, Object) method uses CurrentCulture. What you are trying to do is write another function which does the same thing and call this new function to satisfy a rule, that suggests you don't call such a function. I would just disable the rule or write CultureInfo.CurrentCulture everywhere.

Comment: I understand your argument, but I like the rule.  Half the time I want to use InvariantCulture.  The rule helps to avoid writing a date to the datastore in German format and attempting to read it back out in US format.

Answer (score 1):

I would actually go with the wrapper methods. You can retain your ReSharper warnings, when you attribute your methods with the `JetBrains.Annotations.StringFormatMethodAttribute` of ReSharper.

**Update** I missed the `params` keywoard in the signature. Thanks to @EricMSFT for the comment/hint.

```
[StringFormatMethod("value")]
private string CurrentCulture(string value, params object[] objects) {
    return string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, value, objects);
}
```

The easiest way (there are others like defining the `StringFormatMethodAttribute` in your own codebase) is probably to just reference `"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\ReSharper\v6.1\Bin\JetBrains.Annotations.dll"` in your project.

More details [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Code_Analysis__String_Formatting_Methods.html).

Comment: Thanks, that is an awesome feature of Resharper I didn't know about.  However, it doesn't appear to work for a single object[] argument that contains a variable count of arguments.  It assumes there is a format argument followed by an object for each segment of the format string.

Comment: try (string value, params object[] objects)